# Rails - ActiveAdmin not showing new Resources in Menu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin with Rails 4 and Grape.

I am creating new AA resources with
    `rails g active_admin:resource ModelClassName`
it used to work fine. Every resource showed up as a Menu Link in the Admin Console.

But now for some reason, for the new Models that I am creating, Active Admin is not showing the resources for the same in the Menu.

Any leads to why this could happen would help a lot.

Ruby Version - 2.2.3

Rails Version - 4.2.4

Active Admin Version - 1.0.0

This is my GemFile

```
ruby '2.2.3'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# gem 'unicorn'
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'grape'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'grape-swagger'
```

**EDIT**
The new Model resource doesn't work. But if i rename the Model in the same file to some older model it shows up fine.

Generated ActiveAdmin resource file -

```
ActiveAdmin.register NewModel do # DOESN'T WORK AND DOESN'T SHOW UP IN MENU

    # See permitted parameters documentation:
    # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2 resource-    customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
    #
    # permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
    #
    # or
    #
    # permit_params do
    #   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
    #   permitted << :other if resource.something?
    #   permitted
    # end

end

ActiveAdmin.register OldModel, :as => 'Some Name' do # WORKS AND SHOWS UP IN MENU

    # See permitted parameters documentation:
    # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2 resource-    customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
    #
    # permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
    #
    # or
    #
    # permit_params do
    #   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
    #   permitted << :other if resource.something?
    #   permitted
    # end

end
```

Comment: Show the generated Active Admin class file, especially any 'menu' lines.

Comment: There's no 'menu' lines in the new Resources. Edited the Question to show the generated ActiveAdmin Resource FIles.

Comment: Maybe stick `as: 'New Model'` on the new admin resource file as well?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Finally fixed the issue. I am using a CanCan Adapter to handle what different roles can see on the Admin Console. I didnt remember that I would  need to add the new resources in the roles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `CanCan` gem with your ActiveAdmin, your `models` folder will have a `<proj-name>_admin_ability.rb` file, where you need to add your new model to `can :manage` (or :read) list.

```
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
    can :manage, [User, ModelClassName]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes the new resource could be prevented from showing by an authorization adapter. It could be CanCan or Pundit or any other Authorization system configured with Active Admin.

You can get the specific authorization scheme your active admin is using from `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

on the line that reads
`config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::Adapter`

After getting your Authorization Adapter, you will want to add the new resource to the proper Admin Authorization. Pundit for example, you will want to crate a new policy for the resource allowing an Admin User to carry out specific actions.